# C++ constexpr to generate std::vector

Tags: c++, constexpr

I want to generate code for a vector based on code in a lambda. I think maybe there is a way to do this with constexpr, but I think it would require something particularly clever. Something like [this](http://www.hlsl.co.uk/blog/2017/11/3/c-constexpr-compile-time-lookup-table-generation) seems relevant but the way I want to generate it is more opaque than what is provided. A code example will make this clear:

Consider:

```
auto a = [&]() {
    if(!mem_retire_port->empty() && occupied) {
        auto addr = mem_retire_port->peek()->data.addr;
        if(addr == insns[idx]->ws.pc) {
            occupied = false;
            mem_retire_port->pop();
            insn_decode_port->push(new insn_decode_event_t(insns[idx]));
            idx = (idx + 1) % insns.size();
        }
    }
});
```

I want to generate a std::vector of the form

```
std::vector<std::function<std::string()>> generated_vector = {mem_retire_port->get_name, insn_decode_port->get_name};
```

This information is obviously available to the programmer, but I was wondering if it would be possible to determine this at compile-time programmatically. Maybe a constexpr on operator-> or something to determine if a variable is in the lambda or not.

This question is more about settling my curiosity than providing a perfect solution. I just thought it could be interesting to see if it could be done.

Comment: FWIW, vector has to dynamically allocate space so even if the initializer is a constexpr it wont initialize until run time.

Comment: If nothing else, then your broad capture of everything by reference (`[&]`) will make this more-or-less impossible to evaluate at compile time.

Comment: C++20 is the first C++ standard that has partial support for `constexpr new`. I can't tell if that's enough to do what you want, partially because I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @NathanOliver C++20 adds (some) support for dynamic memory allocation in `constexpr` context though, provided the allocated memory is also released inside the same `constexpr` context.

Comment: I would use `std::array` for `constexpr` like this one. Anyway this looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: How is the code example related to the question? There is no mention of where the vector needs to be generated, or what is `get_name`. Or why a vector of two elements is needed in the first place.

Comment: It can be an std::array – that doesn't really matter – I was just wondering whether without programmer annotation we could programmatically generate the array/vector. get_name is a member function of type std::function<std::string()>>. I need the array for a runtime calculation, which relies on some user input.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because `std::vector` is designed to not be `constexpr`, and there are currently no plans to change this in any upcoming version of the C++ standard.

In theory, what you're trying to do is understandable: `std::vector` by default uses dynamically allocated memory, but it is possible to give it an allocator that allocates memory from static memory instead; and in doing so, it would be *theoretically* possible to (conditionally) make the entire class `constexpr`; or at least the relevant parts.

However. This simply isn't possible right now. If you want a `constexpr` container whose size is variable depending on compilation conditions, you need to roll up something yourself, as `std::vector` is simply not suitable to this purpose.

Maybe do some research to work out if you could use `std::array` with some template metaprogramming black magic to get what you need. There's already a proposal for [`std::make_array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array) which is one way to, at compile-time, get an array the size of which you the programmer don't necessarily have foresight of; so look into seeing whether a similar solution can be applied to your problem.